# Oracle constraint check condition with null and not null

Tags: oracle

My question is about checking constraint, the normal syntax is :

```
ALTER TABLE barracks
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_barracks CHECK( status IN('Destroyed', 'constructed'))
```

This means that column status should be destroyed OR constructed.

In the following I am specifying that barracks doesn't accept null values

```
 ALTER TABLE barracks
 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_barracks CHECK(status IN('Destroyed', 'constructed')
    AND status IS NOT NULL)
```

Now I added  column `colour`. I want to specify **if** `barracks` is **constructed**, then `colour` should be **RED** only and the column **STATUS** should be **NOT NULL**

If BARRACKS IS **DESTROYED**

Then `colour` should be **BLACK** and the column **STATUS** should be **NULL**.

So here is the checking constraint that I wrote:

```
 ALTER TABLE barracks
 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_barracks CHECK( ((status IN ('Destroyed', 'constructed')
         AND status IS NOT NULL) 
         AND (color IN('RED') )) 
    OR (( status IN('Destroyed', 'constructed') 
         AND status IS NULL) 
         AND (color IN('BLACK') )))
```

The problem that if color is RED, I am still able to insert `NULL` into the column `status`. How to solve this constraint in a way it will check my conditions that I have mentioned above?

Comment: _If BARRACKS IS DESTROYED Then colour should be BLACK And the coloumn should be NULL_-- what column should be NULL ???

Comment: @schurik I correct it , column status :)

Comment: it's not possible for the value of the column to be NULL and "Destroyed" **at the same time**. you have to choose either "Destroyed" or NULL :)

Comment: @schurik IF i wrote it in such way, would be better ?
(( status IN('Destroyed', 'constructed') 
         OR status IS NULL)

Comment: @schurik oh well it worked the solution is to replace and with or to be in this way:
 ALTER TABLE barracks
 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_barracks CHECK( (( status IN('Destroyed', 'constructed')
         AND status IS NOT NULL) 
         AND (color IN('RED') )) 
    OR (( status IN('Destroyed', 'constructed') 
         >> OR status IS NULL) 
         AND (color IN('BLACK') )))

Comment: yes it would be better. But its not possible to insert following row with you constraint:insert into barracks (status, color ) values(NULL, 'RED');
  [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b54cd/1) could you post exactly what are you trying to do

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea to use a CHECK constraint to enforce values like 'Destroyed', 'constructed'.  Use a foreign key to a lookup table instead.  Apart from anything else, that would prevent logical absurdities such as  :

```
( status IN('Destroyed', 'constructed') 
         AND status IS NULL)
```

You then also have a simpler check condition:

```
( ( status is not null and color = 'RED') 
   or ( status is null and color = 'BLACK')
```

At the very least you should have two separate check constraints: one to validate the values of STATUS, and one to validate the relationhip between COLOR and whether STATUS is populated.

---

More on the foreign key.  Create a table like this:

```
 create table barracks_statuses
     ( status varchar2 (15) not null
       , constraint bsts_pk primary key (status)
 organization index;

 insert into barracks_statuses values ( 'Destroyed');
 insert into barracks_statuses values ( 'constructed');
```

Then enforce a foreign key like this:

```
alter table barracks
    add constraint barr_bsts_fk foreign key (status)
        references (status);
```

Such an approach is useful because it gives more flexibility.  You add a new status such as 'Planned' or fix the typo in 'constructed' just with DML, instead or rewriting some convoluted check constraint.

Comment: APC What do you mean by :Use a foreign key to a lookup table instead? how a foreign can help me in my table ? and checking it ?

Comment: I have to specify what is the status and what is the color .